Mostrar datos de los usuarios en el carrito con MySQL y Java
Hasta ahora, estoy con un proyecto final y he conseguido hacer la mayor parte gracias a tutoriales, y experiencia propia. Pero ahora estoy estancado en lo siguiente:
El programa es una tienda online (aplicación) en la que haces login con tu usuario ya anteriormente registrado y añades productos a la cesta y haces el pedido.
Mi problema se encuentra en que quiero que en el carrito se muestren los datos del usuario que está loggeado, como su nombre, apellidos, dirección, etc., para luego poder pasarlo a la factura también.
Ahora mismo me da error con que txtNombre es Null.

(Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke
"javax.swing.JTextField.setText(String)" because "this.txtNombre" is
null)

Estos son los códigos que tengo hasta ahora.
Esta es la clase de Consulta:
public Usuario consultarUsuario(String correo, String pass) {
    //PRUEBA 3
    ConexionDB db = new ConexionDB();
    Usuario usuarioLogin = null;

    try (Connection cn = db.conectar(); PreparedStatement pst = cn.prepareStatement("SELECT nombre, apellidos, direccion, ciudad, provincia, c_postal, telefono FROM usuarios WHERE correo =? AND clave =?")) {
        pst.setString(1, correo);
        pst.setString(2, pass);
        try (ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery()) {
            if (rs.next()) {
                // Login successful

                if (correo.equals("admin") && pass.equals("admin")) {
                    // Login de administrador
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login de Administrador correcto");
                    LoginForm lf = new LoginForm();
                    lf.setVisible(false);
                    productos pd = new productos();
                    pd.setVisible(true);
                } else {
                    // Login de usuario

                    usuarioLogin = extractUserData(rs);
                    carrito ct = new carrito();
                    datosUsuario form = ct.new datosUsuario();
                    form.mostrarDatosUsuario(usuarioLogin);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login correcto Bienvenido " + correo);
                    LoginForm lf = new LoginForm();
                    lf.setVisible(false);
                }
            } else {
                // Credenciales invalidas
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correo o contraseña incorrecta");
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    return usuarioLogin;
}

public Usuario extractUserData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
    return new Usuario(
            rs.getString(3),
            rs.getString(4),
            rs.getString(5),
            rs.getString(6),
            rs.getString(7),
            rs.getInt(8),
            rs.getInt(9)
    );

}

Esta es la clase de Usuario (Con sus respectivos getter & Setters):
public class Usuario {


private String nombre;
private String apellidos;
private String direccion;
private String ciudad;
private String provincia;
private int c_postal;
private int telefono;

public Usuario(String nombre, String apellidos, String direccion, String ciudad, String provincia, int c_postal, int telefono) {
    //correo, nombre, apellidos, direccion, ciudad, provincia, c_postal, telefono

    
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.apellidos = apellidos;
    this.direccion = direccion;
    this.ciudad = ciudad;
    this.provincia = provincia;
    this.c_postal = c_postal;
    this.telefono = telefono;

}

El botón de login:
private void jbtnAccesoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    consultas con = new consultas();
    con.consultarUsuario(txtCorreo.getText(), txtPass.getText());
    this.setVisible(false);
    tienda t1 = new tienda(); // Pass Session object to tienda class
    t1.setVisible(true);
}                     

Y aquí están los campos donde quiero que aparezcan los datos en el JFrame Carrito:
public class carrito extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public class datosUsuario {

    private JTextField txtNombre;
    private JTextField txtApellidos;
    private JTextField txtDireccion;
    private JTextField txtCiudad;
    private JTextField txtProvincia;
    private JTextField txtCP;
    private JTextField txtTelefono;

    public void mostrarDatosUsuario(Usuario usuario) {

        txtNombre.setText(usuario.getNombre());
        txtApellidos.setText(usuario.getApellidos());
        txtDireccion.setText(usuario.getDireccion());
        txtCiudad.setText(usuario.getCiudad());
        txtProvincia.setText(usuario.getProvincia());
        txtCP.setText(String.valueOf(usuario.getC_postal()));
        txtTelefono.setText(String.valueOf(usuario.getTelefono()));

    }
}


Buenas, Vini, bienvenido al sitio. El error parece claro, el nombre del usuario es nulo y no puedes ejecutar setText pasando null. Por otro lado, si pones "SELECT *", ¿cómo aseguras que el tercer campo es el nombre? Aparte de eso, en tu código aparecen dos clases llamadas carrito y Carrito. Esto va totalmente contra los estándares de java, los nombres de clase deben empezar con mayúsculas, por un lado, y por otro ¿qué sentido tiene tener dos clases con el mismo nombre diferenciandolas solamente con la primera letra en mayúscula?

@RubioRic Estas en lo correcto, llevo ya una semana con esto y son cosas que no he caido. Ya he cambiado la clase "Carrito" por "datosUsuario" y en "SELECT" (seleccionando cada uno de las columnas(nombre, apellidos, direccion,etc)).
Aunque no entiendo porque me está pasando Null el nombre de usuario...

Puedes ejecutar tu aplicación en modo debug, poniendo un punto de interrupción cuando se llama a extractUserData y examinar exactamente qué está pasando ahí, qué hay exactamente en rs.getString(3)

@RubioRic Pues segun acabo de ver, coge todos los datos perfectamente, y los lleva a la clase Usuario. El problema viene cuando ejecuta la parte de datosUsuario form = ct.new datosUsuario(); form.mostrarDatosUsuario(usuario);
y todos los campos de texto se quedan en Null, vamos que los datos que tiene la clase Usuario no lo carga en los campos de texto.

Edita tu pregunta incluyendo un ejemplo mínimo verificable que refleje la relación entre tu JFrame principal y este otro en el que quieres cargar los datos de un usuario. Da la sensación de que el problema está ahí. Quizás te falte un repaint que haga que se refresque como se muestran los textfields.

@RubioRic Ya lo solucioné... Lo que hace un dia de descanso... El problema es que los private JTextField txtNombre; estaban vacios, como dijimos. Pero luego pensé que si no llamaba el metodo para llenarlos, no iba a funcionar nunca. public datosUsuario(JTextField txtNombre,etc) // this.txtNombre = txtNombre; y llamandolos en el constructor luego y ya conseguí que funcionase. Muchas gracias, porque realmente con el Debug, pude ver donde empezó a fallar.

De nada. Pero más que editar el título de la pregunta, puedes añadir como una respuesta lo que has hecho para solucionarlo. :-)

El formato de sitio es de preguntas y respuestas. Pon en la zona de respuestas qué te ha sido útil para resolver tu problema, en base a [answer].
